# Cannot boot or restore iPad2

Tags: ipad, startup, restore

I have an old iPad2 which, I was using for a very long time. Recently it started to act weird. Not waking up, or acting much slower than it should (with iOS 9.3.4). I've wipe-restored it once, reduced the number of applications to a minimum (to reduce background refresh load). It was happily humming along to watch some Netflix shows or read and annotate some PDFs. Until it wasn't.

One day it failed to wake up, and I restarted it somehow (home/power combo IIRC) while connected to my Mac. I charged it, checked its battery stats (with Coconut Battery), and it was good (~%85 health IIRC). Then unplugged, and put it away.

Yesterday, it didn't wake again. This time home/power combo didn't restart to device. Its screen was black (with backlight off). I connected to my Mac, iTunes reported that it's in recovery mode. I confirmed the wipe and upgrade to 9.3.5. iTunes downloaded the iOS image, rebooted the device, and the progress bar came on. However after 8 hours, there was no progress and iTunes was Waiting for iPad. I disconnected the iPad, restarted with home/power combo and the screen stayed black.

Still cannot boot or restore the device. Any suggestions, help?